# Does playing on a server in a different region give players in the same region an edge over those who are not?

Tags: battlefield-4

I've wondered whether this is the case as I am not entirely sure myself. I have been looking around but I haven't found a solid answer yet. Personally, I think it is cheating although I am not sure.

Comment: Do you mean latency wise? Where some people are closer to the server therefore have a better connection or something else? Please elaborate a little bit further.

Comment: more if I'm playing in Europe and I'm in a U.S server will there be a time delay for me ?

Comment: Yes, if you're further from the server you can expect more lag. Whether this can be exploited depends on the game but it's usually a disadvantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latency wise, if you are connecting from EU to a US server then you can expect some lag although not a heck ton (varies from server to server). The players connecting to the same server from the US will have a minor edge although not a whole lot, to the contrary; If you were, for example, connecting to a US server from Australia you could expect some hefty latency (Most of the time).

It's not at all 'cheating' in any way as far as I know. If you'd prefer to avoid these latency issues just try connect to a server in the EU (If you are there; otherwise connect to a server in the same region).

Answer (score 1):

yes, it DOES give you an advantage if you are playing out of your region.  the reason behind this is lag compensation which the above responders did not account for.

because you are so far away from the server the game actually tries to account for that by slowing down the local players connection.  ie:  on my screen(USA) i turned a corner and fired 22 rounds into your character while you only fired 2 rounds(on my screen).  the netcode, happening behind the scenes, takes the amount of time/your lag into consideration and gives you a slight boost so as to make it a "fair trade" firefight.

so even though i saw myself dump almost an entire clip into you and you only fired 2 rounds the outcome is that i died and MAYBE you died also.  that was "kill trading" which was supposedly patched but now the win goes to the slower/out of region player.

there are many videos on youtube that go into greater detail on this subject.

a DICE developer also admitted that players with slower/further connections from the server DO in fact gain an advantage.  source: http://www.reddit.com/r/battlefield_4/comments/299pjb/cte_patch_is_going_to_be_released_in_34_hours/ciixr5h

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does in fact give the players in the same region an advantage. The game lags more the netcode registers slower and you are delayed. Even if it’s a little in an online competive match it can make the biggest difference, especially in fast paced games.  It almost completely stops split second reactions and instinctive movements. It’s also like you have to play an entire game while pre determining moves in the future.

In a shooting game you may be shooting someone but the hits don’t register because the enemy isn’t in that same exact spot anymore but you can’t see it because you're delayed and even if you do hit them the shots are delayed.

In a fighting game you may had threw a punch in exactly the right time but the punch is delayed and they moved. Or you may not even be able to defend yourself because you were trying to block something as soon as it hit you but you can’t because the game didn’t register it until a second later wen it’s already too late.

In sports games like basketball where you have to time your shot perfectly to make a shot or defend but you can’t defend how you want unless you pre determine your moves.

This happens inside of the US as well as there is an east and west region for it. Some games show you the region you're playing on and some don’t but it still affects the players if it isn’t their region.